# Who sends and who reveive SIGTRAP in case of interupt 3?

Tags: gdb

In a debugging session, when the deugger wants to set a breakpoint, it replaces an instruction by int3. When the Target process reach this instruction, the process stops. I have read that a signal is send at this time. But i did not manage to capture this signal (i wrote my own mini debugger for testing). Who send this signal ? The kernel? And who is the receiver?
I had to put a wait() fonction juste after the ptrace_cont. Do you think this is this wait function that catch the signal in order to notify the debugger that the process reach a break point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the Target process reach this instruction, the process stops.

That's not quite accurate. When the trap instruction (`0xCC` on x86) is executed, the processor notifies the OS. On UNIX, the OS checks to see whether the process is being `ptrace`d by somebody.

If no, the `SIGTRAP` signal is delivered to the application, which usually results in process being killed (but you can catch and handle the signal in the application).

If there *is* a `ptrace`er (usually a debugger), then the signal is not delivered to the application. Instead, debugger's `wait` is unblocked to notify the debugger that the inferior has changed state. The debugger then looks at where the inferior process stopped, discovers that it did so because of a breakpoint, and handles the situation as appropriate (let's you examine the inferior, or resumes it if the breakpoint is conditional and current conditions don't match, etc.)