# Alloc memory in debugged process

Tags: gdb, elf

I am attaching a process with ptrace syscall. It is possible to read/write memory with peek and poke but i want to alloc some memory in the remote process. Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to alloc some memory in the remote process. Is it possible to do this ?

Presumably you want to allocate some memory using process's own `malloc` . Proof by existence:

```
(gdb) start
(gdb) print malloc(20)
$1 = 0x820430
```

So yes, it's possible.

The details are however quite messy: you'll need to read symbol table for the inferior process in order to find where it's `malloc` is, then construct a proper call frame and transfer control to `malloc`s address using correct ABI for your target process, and finally clean all of that up.

This is at least 10x harder than what you asked for in your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37897450/50617) [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37897347/50617) questions.

Comment: Great but how does this works ? If i want to program this in C ? (suppose the process is attached with ptrace syscall). Do you think i should change manually eip in order to call malloc then go back to previous eip ?

Comment: "How does this work?" -- as I said, it's complicated. You can start by reading GDB sources, but be prepared for a *long* uphill battle. You'll want to look at `call_function_by_hand` in `infrun.c`.

Comment: Depending on your need, you might trigger a `mmap` `MAP_ANONYMOUS` syscall instead.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75042559/52499)?